# EasyAdmin 3 datetime picker time format

Tags: symfony, easyadmin3

How to change native easy admin 3 in symfony date/time picker time format? It now renders month, day, year. How do you set to 'Y-m-d H:i'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in the [source code for the `DateTimeField`](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/src/Field/DateTimeField.php#L77) you will find a `setFormat` method that accepts a valid ICU Datetime Pattern (see http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

The format of a *native* date picker is determined by the browser's *native* code and locale settings, you cannot change it with out some complicated scripting ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)). This may possibly update the format of a choice or text type (not tested).

Try something like this:

```
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateTimeField;


public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [

        // native date picker format cannot be changed
        // Uses native HTML5 widgets when rendering this field in forms.
        DateTimeField::new('beginsAt')->setFormat('Y-MM-dd HH:mm')->renderAsNativeWidget(),

        // Uses <select> lists when rendering this field in forms.
        DateTimeField::new('beginsAt')->setFormat('Y-MM-dd HH:mm')->renderAsChoice(),

        // Uses <input type="text"> elements when rendering this field in forms.
        DateTimeField::new('beginsAt')->setFormat('Y-MM-dd HH:mm')->renderAsText(),
    ];
}
```

Comment: It does change how date is rendered in crud index page, but it does not change native date picker widget format.

Comment: @EvaldasAi you cannot change the format of a native date picker, the browser has total control over that and its based on the user's locale. I'll edit my answer, maybe it will work for formatting choice or text.